# How do I generate to a different project?

Tags: typewriter

So we are starting a new angular / webapi project, and we are splitting it up such that the client and the rest API are in 2 separate projects.  The client project has no server-executed code.  Just html and typescript (which we transpile to javascript, of course)

I want for my typewriter-generated DTOs to land in the client, but I don't even want to reference the WebAPI project from my client project.  How can I set up the template so that when I save a change to my DTO, the typescript file is written to my client app?  (or is there a different way to accomplish this?)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As long as the two projects are in the same solution you can render the template from the client project without adding a reference to the API project.

To do this you'll need to add a constructor to the tst-template to include the API project.

```
${
    Template(Settings settings)
    {
        settings.IncludeProject("Project.Name");
    }
}
$Classes(...)[...]
```

Have a look at http://frhagn.github.io/Typewriter/pages/getting-started.html#settings

Comment: Awesome!  Thank you!

Comment: In my case, the API project is in different solution. And my UI project is in a separate solution. How to render the template from the client project? Any suggestions? Thank you!